# Python tkinter updating canvas label outside the main function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to update the canvas label outside the function that canvas was created.

```
def Application_GUI():
    global Scanned_serial
    global label1
    global label2
    global window
    global label_gaminys
    global canvas_tk
    window = Tk()   # create a GUI window 
    window.geometry("1920x1080") # set the configuration of GUI window
    canvas_tk = Canvas(window,bg='ivory2',width=1920,height=1080)
    canvas_tk.pack()
    label1=Label(canvas_tk,text = "SKENUOKITE BARKODA(GUID) ARBA DAIKTO RIVILINI KODA:",bg='ivory2')
    entry = Entry(canvas_tk) # entry = guid
    canvas_tk.create_window(960,50,window=label1)
    canvas_tk.create_window(960,100,window=entry)
    var = IntVar()
    button = Button(canvas_tk,text="Testi operacija",width = 30,height=2,command = lambda: var.set(1))
    button2 = Button(canvas_tk,text="RESTART DEVICES",width = 30,height=2,command = lambda:restart_devices(myConnection))
    ota_button = Button(canvas_tk, text="OTA", width=30, height=1, command=OTA_gui)
    canvas_tk.create_window(960,150,window=button)
    canvas_tk.create_window(960,200,window=button2)
    canvas_tk.create_window(960,250,window=ota_button)
    
# ********************* IMPORTANT PART *************************
    label_gaminys=Label(canvas_tk,text = "GAMINIO KODAS:",bg='ivory2')
    canvas_tk.create_window(960,450,window=label_gaminys)
    
# ***************************************************************
    
    print("waiting...")    
    button.wait_variable(var)
    result = entry.get()
    print("result=",result) 
    Scanned_serial = entry.get()
    label2=Label(window,text = "Vykdoma operacija:")
    label2.pack()
   
    window.update()
```

In the function above, I am creating my user interface using a canvas. The important line of code is there:

```
    label_gaminys=Label(canvas_tk,text = "GAMINIO KODAS:",bg='ivory2')
    canvas_tk.create_window(960,450,window=label_gaminys)
```

I have created a window for a text at location 960,450.

I want to update this label outside this GUI function during a operation .

```
def Full_operation():
    #Destroy previous window
    window.destroy()
    
    #create a new GUI window
    Application_GUI()
    global canvas_tk
    operacijos_kodas=Scanning_operation(myConnection,Scanned_serial)
        
    elif(operacijos_kodas == 1):
        insertData_komplektacija(myConnection,"fmb110bbv801.csv");
        update_current_operation(myConnection);
        #label2.config(text = "Take items from the box:")#update the label2
        label_gaminys=Label(canvas_tk,text = "Gamninio kodas=%s"%(Scanned_serial),bg='ivory2')
        canvas_tk.create_window(960,450,window=label_gaminys)
        picking_operation(myConnection,label2);
```

The function above describes the operatio. I want to modify the label inside this function. I have described my canvas_tk as global and initialise in this function so I can access and modify it. I have managed to update the label by creating a new window as following:

```
        label_gaminys=Label(canvas_tk,text = "Gamninio kodas=%s"%(Scanned_serial),bg='ivory2')
        canvas_tk.create_window(960,450,window=label_gaminys)
        picking_operation(myConnection,label2);
```

But that does not seem like a correct way to do that since I am not actually "updating" the label, instead I am creating a new window and assigning it to a new label.

Could someone give me some general advice on how to do that properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a function that does this:

```
label_gaminys["text'] = "" #Insert the text you want into it and then the text changes
```

and then you can modify it whilst being in the same window. On another note, do notice that your Full_operation has an `elif` in it without an `if` first (just notifying you, because if there is no if before it it will cause an error).